# How to Display Username in the homepage using ASP MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

How to Display the User Id in my Homepage in ASP MVC. I don't know what is the problem. May I know what are the cause the userId

This is the part of Dashboard

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      
         string sUserInfo = System.Environment.UserName;
  string constr = "Data Source=MyDatabase;Database=test;User Id=username;Password=add3" ;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select SystemName from tbl_SYS_Users where UserId='" + sUserInfo + "'");
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string tempa = "";
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            tempa += sdr["SystemName"].ToString();
        }         
              
                lblUserID.Text = Utilities.GetUserInfo(tempa);
    }
```

This is for the Utilities in AppData Folder

```
public static string GetUserInfo(string sSystem)
    {
        sSystem = sSystem.ToUpper();
        string sUserInfo = System.Environment.UserName;
        if (SetConfigs()) //Check config file first
        {
            //Get userinfo from db server
            if (sSystem != "HOME")
            {
                string sQry = "Select * from tbl_SYS_Users where SystemName = '" + sSystem + "' AND  UserId='" + sUserInfo + "'";
                using (DataTable dsTable = SQL_Query(Globals.sSQLCS_FNS, sQry, true, false))
                {
                    if (dsTable == null)
                    {
                        sUserInfo += " - Unknown User!a";
                        Globals.UserID = null;
                        Globals.UserAccess = "";
                        Globals.UserName = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (dsTable.Rows.Count == 0) //ID not found!
                        {
                            sUserInfo += " - Unknown User!";
                            Globals.UserID = null;
                            Globals.UserAccess = "";
                            Globals.UserName = null;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sUserInfo += " - " + dsTable.Rows[0]["Username"];
                            Globals.UserID = dsTable.Rows[0]["UserId"].ToString().Trim(); 
                            Globals.UserName = dsTable.Rows[0]["Username"].ToString().Trim();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (sSystem != "HOME")
            sUserInfo += " - Unknown User!s";

        return sUserInfo; // return to lblUserID.Text in the homepage
    }
```

This image is the homepage

[image]

This is the database

[image]

I Want to display the Username in my Homepage

Comment: When you put breakpoint what is sSystem value?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use parameters for your query as well.  You don't want to be a victim of an SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

inject usermanager in to the view and add this

```
@UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the scope of Globals class? It seems when page loads class object initialized and all becomes empty. Declare Globals class as static (If not).

Comment: Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to write a good answer.